# Правильно ли у меня написанны алгоритмы прямого и обратного распостранения для нейроной сети на Python?

Tags: python, numpy, нейронные-сети, градиент

Я решил написать с нуля (в целях обучения и понимания темы) пару классов которые должны в совокупности представлять нейронную сеть. Вопрос заключается в том правильно ли я написал алгоритмы для прямого и обратного распространения сети (смещения я пока не добавлял намеренно)?

Библиотеки:

```
import typing
import numpy
import numpy as np
```

Класс который представляет собой нейрон:

```
class HiddenNeuron:
    def __init__(self, vector_weight: np.ndarray, index_in_layer: int = None, index_in_site: int = None):
        self.__weight_vector = vector_weight
        self.__weighted_sum = None
        self.__active_value = None
        self.__index_in_layer = index_in_layer
        self.__index_in_site = index_in_site

    @property
    def index_in_layer(self):
        return self.__index_in_layer

    @property
    def index_in_site(self):
        return self.__index_in_site

    @property
    def weight_vector(self):
        return self.__weight_vector

    def set_weight_value(self, index, value):
        self.__weight_vector[index] = value

    def weigh_sum(self, input_vector: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        self.__weighted_sum = np.dot(input_vector, self.__weight_vector)
        return self.weighted_sum

    def activate_neuron(self, func: typing.Callable) -> float:
        if self.__weighted_sum is None:
            raise ErrorRoJQ("Вы пытаетесь взвесить пустую сумму!")
        self.__active_value = func(self.__weighted_sum)
        return self.__active_value

    @property
    def weighted_sum(self) -> None | np.ndarray:
        return self.__weighted_sum

    @property
    def active_value(self) -> None | float:
        return self.__active_value
```

Класс который представляет собой скрытый слой:

```
class HiddenLayer:
    def __init__(self, number_of_neurons: int, weight_max: int, input_vector_len: int, index_in_site: int = None):
        self.__input_vector_len = input_vector_len
        self.__neuron_list: list[HiddenNeuron] = []
        self.__neuron_active_values: None | list = []
        self.__neuron_weight_sum: None | list = []
        self.__index_in_site = index_in_site
        for index_in_layer in range(number_of_neurons):
            vector_weights = np.array([np.random.random() * weight_max for i in range(input_vector_len)])
            new_neuron = HiddenNeuron(vector_weights, index_in_layer, index_in_site)
            self.__neuron_list.append(new_neuron)

    def __getitem__(self, item: int):
        return self.__neuron_list[item]

    def weigh_sum(self, input_vector: np.ndarray):
        if len(input_vector) != self.__input_vector_len:
            raise ErrorRoJQ("Длинна входного вектора, не совпадает с указаной длиной вектора весов для данного слоя!")
        new_neuron_list = []
        self.__neuron_weight_sum =[]
        for neuron_obj in self.__neuron_list:
            weight_sum = neuron_obj.weigh_sum(input_vector)
            self.__neuron_weight_sum.append(weight_sum)
            new_neuron_list.append(neuron_obj)
        self.__neuron_list = new_neuron_list

    def activate_layer(self, activate_func: typing.Callable):
        new_neuron_list = []
        self.__neuron_active_values = []
        for neuron_obj in self.__neuron_list:
            active_value = neuron_obj.activate_neuron(activate_func)
            self.__neuron_active_values.append(active_value)
            new_neuron_list.append(neuron_obj)
        self.__neuron_list = new_neuron_list

    def weigh_sum_and_activate_layer(self, input_vector, activate_func):
        self.weigh_sum(input_vector)
        self.activate_layer(activate_func)

    @property
    def neurons_active_values(self):
        return self.__neuron_active_values

    @property
    def neurons(self):
        return self.__neuron_list

    @property
    def neurons_weight_sum(self):
        return self.__neuron_weight_sum

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__neuron_list)
```

Класс который представляет собой саму сеть:

```
class NeuronSite:
    def __init__(self, hidden_layers: int,
                 hidden_layer_length: int,
                 weights_max: int,
                 input_vector_len: int,
                 output_vector_len: int):
        def generate_hidden_layer(vector_len_: int, neurons_in_layer: int, index_in_site: int):
            new_layer = HiddenLayer(neurons_in_layer, weights_max, vector_len_, index_in_site)
            return new_layer
        self.__hidden_layers: list[HiddenLayer] = []
        self.__input_vector_len = input_vector_len
        self.__output_vector_len = output_vector_len
        vector_len = input_vector_len
        # Генерация скрытых слоев
        for i in range(hidden_layers):
            self.__hidden_layers.append(generate_hidden_layer(vector_len, hidden_layer_length, i))
            vector_len = hidden_layer_length
        self.__hidden_layers.append(generate_hidden_layer(vector_len, output_vector_len, hidden_layers))

    def forward_direction(self, input_vector: np.ndarray, activate_func: typing.Callable):
        current_input_vector = input_vector
        if len(input_vector) != self.__input_vector_len:
            raise ErrorRoJQ("Входной вектор имеет не ту длину!")
        for hidden_layer in self.__hidden_layers:
            hidden_layer.weigh_sum_and_activate_layer(current_input_vector, activate_func)
            current_input_vector = hidden_layer.neurons_active_values
        output_value = self.__hidden_layers[-1].neurons_active_values
        return output_value

    def backpropagation(self, out_vector: list, learn_step: float, need_vector: np.ndarray):
        def move_weight(neuron_: HiddenNeuron):
            for weight_index, weight_value in enumerate(neuron_.weight_vector):
                back_layer_index = neuron_.index_in_site - 1
                back_layer = self.__hidden_layers[back_layer_index]
                gradient_descent = (neuron_.weighted_sum - need_vector.sum()) * back_layer.neurons[weight_index].active_value
                new_weight = weight_value - learn_step * gradient_descent
                neuron_.set_weight_value(weight_index, new_weight)

        cost_value = RootMeanSquareEstimation.function(need_vector.sum(), sum(out_vector))
        print(f"Значение функции ошибки: {cost_value}")
        for hidden_layer in self.__hidden_layers:
            for neuron in hidden_layer.neurons:
                move_weight(neuron)
        return cost_value
```

Класс который используется для оценки(CostFunction):

```
class RootMeanSquareEstimation:
    @staticmethod
    def function(y: float, x: float):
        """
        :param y: need_vector sum
        :param x: out_vector sum
        :return:
        """
        return 0.5 * (y - x)**2

    @staticmethod
    def derivative_x(y, x):
        return x - y

    @staticmethod
    def derivative_y(y, x):
        return y - x
```

Comment: А что мешает самому выполнить отладку написанного кода? Взять данные, запустить код, сравнить с ожидаемым ответом, найти как исправить код, что-бы ответ соответствовал ожидаемому? Вы хотите, что-бы кто-то это сделал за вас? Тогда ваша цель -  "обучения и понимания темы" -  точно выполнен не будет. Вернее, кто-то другой может и улучшит свое понимание, но только не вы. И вообще, просто для информации. 15-20% работы программиста -  это написание кода. 80-85% - это его отладка, доведение кода "до ума". Т.е. именно то, вы хотите, что-бы за вас кто-то сделал. Так это не работает.

Comment: @passant Спасибо, что разъяснили данный момент, и сам так считаю, но хочу уточнить, что я не прошу делать отладку, я спрашиваю правильно ли в теории поведение моей программы на конкретно  теоретическом уровне, я не хочу, что бы кто-то это за меня делал, я лишь спрашиваю не сделал ли я грубых ошибок. То есть если более понятно я спрашиваю правильно ли я проецировал (написал) математические формулы на синтаксис языка Python.

Comment: Ну так что-бы ответить на эти вопросы как раз и делается отладка. "Глазами" это никто не проверит нормально. Запускаешь, смотришь результат, сравниваешь с задуманным, ищешь ошибку. Другого способа нет. Что такое "конкретно теоретический уровень"  программы и что такое "поведение программы в теории" - мягко говоря не понял.

Comment: @passant Я имел ввиду сами формулы, будь то это градиентный спуск и функция подсчета ошибки и перенес ли я правильно их смысл.